# A ClassBlock was used after being disposed. Once you have called dispose() on a ClassBlock, it can no longer be used

Tags: flutter

My ClassBloc

```
List<dynamic> _products = [];
ClassBlock({this.auth, this.products})

}

MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
       value: Auth(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ClassBlock>(
      update: (ctx, auth, prevData) => ClassBloc(auth.token, auth.userId,
        prevData == null ? [] : prevData.operatori),
   ),])
```

A ClassBlock was used after being disposed. Once you have called dispose() on a ClassBlock, it can no longer be used.

Comment: Add mode where you are using? And how you are using?

Comment: using multi-provider in main.dart and when ever i hotload the application it showed this error to me so i have to rerun